# What causes the type initializer for 'System.Management.MTAHelper' to throw an exception

Tags: .net, winforms

...and how to resolve it?

The is thrown from 32bit .Net app that is run on a 64bit Windows.

The machine has the require .Net framework installed.

> Mozilla/4.0(compatible; MSIE 8.0;
> Windows NT 6.1; WOW64;  Trident/4.0;
> SLCC2; .Net CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR
> 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729;  Media  Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)

EDIT:
Here's the inner exception

> Exception Source: System.Management
>
> Exception Type: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>
> Exception Message: Retrieving the COM class factory for component
> with CLSID {A8F03BE3-EDB7-4972-821F-AF6F8EA34884} failed due to the following error: 80040154.
>
> Exception Target Site: .cctor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an [MSDN post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2010/10/20/get-wmiobject-the-type-initializer-for-system-management-mtahelper-threw-an-exception.aspx) that reports the same problem, with a solution:

> So I went to HKCR\CLSID{A8F03BE3-EDB7-4972-821F-AF6F8EA34884}\InprocServer32(Default) in my x64 environment, and saw the following path: C:\Windows\system32\mscoree.dll.
>
> Customer changed the C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\mscoree.dll path he found in there to the right one, and he didn't get the error again.

There's no explanation given for why the path might be wrong, but it seems it worked... you could at least check that registry setting and see whether it looks wrong on the box in question.

Comment: Hah! I found the same post on google after posting this question. I'll try that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just solved it!
I had to reinstall .NET 1.1 on windows 7.
Here is how:

Downloaded: http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=262D25E3-F589-4842-8157-034D1E7CF3A3&displaylang=en
Downloaded: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=a8f5654f-088e-40b2-bbdb-a83353618b38&displaylang=en

Then:

```
mkdir c:\dotnetfx
c:\DotNet
dotnetfx.exe /T:c:\dotnetfx /C
c:\dotnetfx\msiexec.exe /a netfx.msi TARGETDIR=C:\DotNet
NDP1.1sp1-KB867460-X86.exe /Xp:C:\DotNet\netfxsp.msp
msiexec.exe /a c:\DotNet\netfx.msi /p c:\DotNet\netfxsp.msp
C:\DotNet\netfx.msi
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without further details, but when you get a `TypeInitializationException`, check the `InnerException`, it usually contains the underlying reason.

Comment: inner exception added to question.